# Center align td's, not text length

Tags: html, css, html-table, center

How to center align td tags instead of centering the whole text length?
For example:

```
<tr>
<td>testtest</td>
<td>testtest</td>
<td>Centered</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
```

The 2 `<td>`'s before the centered td have a longer text length, so if I align the `<tr>` it wont center the middle `<td>`, is it possible to ignore the text length and just look at the `<td>`'s?

Comment: Try to this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/cdy8f/1/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 <td style="text-align: center;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `text-align:center;` CSS property to td as

```
td{
 text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

**HTML**

```
<table >

    <tr>
<td>testtest</td>
<td>testtest</td>
<td class="center">Centered</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

**Css**

```
table {
    width:100%;border:solid 1px red;    
}
td{width:15%;}
.center{width:40%;background:green;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/cdy8f/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the width of td:

```
td{
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 200px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cdy8f/2/)